# Cmake can't find compiler without editing PATH

Tags: c++, c, cmake

so what i am doing is that i am having 2 targets in a project, one is program for embedded device that i am crosscompiling, and the second are tests. I need to build them with 2 different compilers.

To main project i am passing arm compiler path by file toolchain.cmake and its working fine.
But right now i would like to build also the tests without having to add path to mingw64/bin to my environment variables (yes its working if i do that).

Test project is added as:

```
ExternalProject_Add(${UNIT_TEST_TARGET}
SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/
    PREFIX ${UNIT_TEST_TARGET}
    CMAKE_ARGS ${GTEST_ARGS}
    BUILD_ALWAYS TRUE
    INSTALL_COMMAND cmake -E echo "Skipping install step."
    EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)
```

So right now i would like to pass to this external project file toolchaintests.cmake which looks like :

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER  <my_path_here>/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER <my_path_here>/mingw64/bin/g++.exe)
```

with:

```
list(APPEND GTEST_ARGS "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/toolchaintests.cmake")
```

and if i do this cmake can't recognize the compilers:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler:  <my_path_here>/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler:  <my_path_here>/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
  The C compiler

    " <my_path_here>/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"
```

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

```
    Change Dir:  <my_path_here>/out/build/tests/src/tests-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/Ninja/ninja-win/ninja.exe cmTC_a1c48 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_a1c48.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj
    FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_a1c48.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
      <my_path_here>\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_a1c48.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c  <my_path_here>\out\build\tests\src\tests-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Can i do this somehow else?

Comment: Continue reading the output till the end and follow the last line.

Comment: there's normally a log file with more details

Comment: The installation instructions for Mingw explicitly tells you that its installation folder needs to be added to the PATH. What's the problem, why can't you just add it to PATH?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Installation%20of%20binary%20toolchain%20packages/

Comment: @Lundin thank you sir, i think this is good enough answer for me. We just have problems with setting it up with jenkins and we were trying to find a way around editing path.

Comment: What you plan, is good and often done. But you need an environment setup that allows to distinguish the compilers by their executable's name, and that all can be found via PATH. That's why cross-compilers are often callable with a prefix. This way your system's native compiler is the casual "gcc", and your target's compiler can be "arm-xxx-gcc".